# Turning "4W2R" to "WWWWRR" Error - Exception thrown: write access violation

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings, function-definition

The goal of the program is to turn a string like this - "4R2W5X" to this > 'RRRRWWXXXXX"
I got a template of a prepared code and I had to fill out the empty spaces, you can notice that I'm not using all the variables they give in the template.

I get an error when I try to run this (I'll mark the error line in the code) - access violation

The template without my answers is down below, you can see where it asks to fill the empty space.

```
void main()
{
char source[40];
char dest[200];

decode(source, dest);
printf("%s\n", dest);
}

void decode(char* source, char* dest)
{
    int digit; 
    char* chr = " ";
    int expander;
    int legal_digit;
    char* orginal_dest = dest;

    if ((digit = atoi(source)/10)!=0)
    {
        strcpy(dest, "ERROR: odd number of chars\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while ((*source >= '0') && (*source <= '9'))
        {
            *chr = *source; // This is where I get the error.
            source++;
            digit = atoi(*source);
            for (expander = 0; expander < digit; expander++)
            {
                *dest = *chr;
                dest++;
            }
            source++;
        }
        if (*source == '\0')
        {
            *dest = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(orginal_dest, "ERROR: digit not found where expected");
        }
    }
}
```

The template:

```
void decode(char* source, char* dest)
{
    int digit; 
    char* chr = " ";
    int expander;
    int legal_digit;
    char* orginal_dest = dest;

    if ( (1) !=0) // Fill (1)
    {
        strcpy(dest, "ERROR: odd number of chars\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while ((*source >= '0') && (*source <= '9'))
        {
            *chr = *source; // This is where I get the error.
            source++;
            digit = (2); // Fill (2)
            for (expander = 0; expander < digit; expander++)
            {
                *dest = (3); // Fill (3) 
                dest++;
            }
            source++;
        }
        if (*source == '\0')
        {
            *dest = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            (4) (orginal_dest, "ERROR: digit not found where expected"); // Fill (4)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who prepared this template does not know C. You may not change a string literal like char* chr = " "; ...  *chr = *source;

Comment: My teacher is not a 100, is it right that he needed to allocate memory first?
char* chr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);

Comment: It is just a bad code. Variables should be declared where they are used. Moreover the variable int legal_digit; is not used within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the access violation is an attempt to change a string literal

```
char* chr = " ";
//...
*chr = *source; // This is where I get the error
```

Though in C opposite to C++ string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

The provided code template demonstrates a bad style of programming.

For example the first function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the source string is not being changed within the function. The function should return pointer to the destination string.

Variables should be declared where they are used. Moreover the variable

```
int legal_digit;
```

is not used within the function.

Using the approach implemented in the function the function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
char * decode( const char *source, char *dest )
{
    if ( strlen( source ) % 2 != 0 ) // Fill (1)
    {
        strcpy( dest, "ERROR: odd number of chars" );
    }
    else
    {
        char *orginal_dest = dest;

        while ( ( *source >= '0' ) && ( *source <= '9' ) )
        {
            char chr = *source;
            source++;
            unsigned int digit = chr - '0'; // Fill (2)
            for ( unsigned int expander = 0; expander < digit; expander++ )
            {
                *orginal_dest = *source; // Fill (3) 
                orginal_dest++;
            }
            source++;
        }

        if ( *source == '\0' )
        {
            *orginal_dest = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy( dest, "ERROR: digit not found where expected" ); // Fill (4)
        }
    }

    return dest;
}
```